# Genetic algorithm grammar induction program/code?

Tags: grammar, genetic-algorithm, context-free-grammar, grammar-induction

Does anyone know of a program that uses a GA to perform grammar induction/inference, I've read tonnes of research papers and articles on this stuff like Lankhorst and De Pauw but I can't find any implementations or programmes that use this technique anywhere. Any help on this greatly appreciated, cheers

Comment: I don't ever heard on this. You should trying making one, it sounds like a good idea.

Comment: Have you tried emailing the authors of the papers to find if they are willing to give you the implementation?

Answer (score 0):

I think the work by Oscar Nierstrasz, Markus Kobel and Tudor Gîrba in the context of the MOOSE framework and "agile modeling" could be starting point. They want to infer grammars for programming languages and their dialects, and they make a point of making their tools available in the public domain.

Comment: I also found a few papers about [stochastic context-free grammar induction](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C50&q=%22grammar+induction%22+%22genetic+algorithm%22+%22stochastic+context-free%22&btnG=) using genetic algorithms.